# babylonjs - how do i move or scale an imported mesh out of its scope?

Tags: babylonjs

[failed attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFgUB.png)

here are some forced attempts to do it, inside BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh...{ newMeshes[0].position.x=10; }  it works using the local item newMeshes[0], but out of this nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the variable `newMeshes` is only defined inside the callback function. If you want to get the variable outside of the function you need it to be defined in the global scope. To do this simply declare a variable before `ImportMesh` is called and inside of `ImportMesh`'s callback function set that variable to `newMeshes[0]` like this:

```
var meshisin = BABYLON.AbstractMesh;
// Define the variable in the global scope.
var skullMesh;
meshisin = BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "scenes/", "skull.babylon", scene, function (newMeshes) {
    skullMesh = newMeshes[0];
});
```

Then you can change the position of the mesh with: `skullMesh.position.x = 10;`.

But since it takes say 1 second to load the mesh you delay using the mesh until it's loaded with a `setTimeout` like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    skullMesh.position.x = 10;
}, 1000);
```

All in all your code would become:

```
var meshisin = BABYLON.AbstractMesh;
// Define the variable in the global scope.
var skullMesh;
meshisin = BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "scenes/", "skull.babylon", scene, function (newMeshes) {
    skullMesh = newMeshes[0];
});

setTimeout(function() {
    skullMesh.position.x = 10;
}, 1000);
```

PS: It's generally not a good idea to post code in images.